# Debugging and android assembly dump

Tags: android, assembly, android-ndk

I'm using the ndk-gdb to help understand a bug that keeps happening at random on an Android game.

I managed to get an assembly dump and I am stepping through it in order to locate the bug.  However I am new to assemble language and I am literally learning on the job. I wonder if any one can help decipher a few lines of code and help point me in the right direction so that I may make a decent attempt at deciphering the rest of the dump?

```
     0xa3b56ec0 <Game::Draw(SpriteRenderer&)+36>:     add.w   lr, r0, #48     ; 0x30
   0xa3b56ec4 <Game::Draw(SpriteRenderer&)+40>:     add     r4, sp, #148    ; 0x94
=> 0xa3b56ec6 <Game::Draw(SpriteRenderer&)+42>:     ldmia.w lr!, {r5, r6, r8, r9}
   0xa3b56eca <Game::Draw(SpriteRenderer&)+46>:     stmia.w r4!, {r5, r6, r8, r9}
   0xa3b56ece <Game::Draw(SpriteRenderer&)+50>:     ldmia.w lr, {r5, r6, r8, r9, r10}
   0xa3b56ed2 <Game::Draw(SpriteRenderer&)+54>:     stmia.w r4, {r5, r6, r8, r9, r10}
   0xa3b56ed6 <Game::Draw(SpriteRenderer&)+58>:     ldr.w   lr, [r0]
   0xa3b56eda <Game::Draw(SpriteRenderer&)+62>:     ldr     r4, [r0, #4]
```

I'm aware that data is being passed between registers. I am also aware that this is the ARM assembly language being used.

Im especially curios about what is taking place in these two lines here:

```
=> 0xa3b56ec6 <Game::Draw(SpriteRenderer&)+42>:     ldmia.w lr!, {r5, r6, r8, r9}
       0xa3b56eca <Game::Draw(SpriteRenderer&)+46>:     stmia.w r4!, {r5, r6, r8, r9}
```

Is the 32 bit contents of five registered being accessed?

Comment: Yes, that's copying some memory using the registers for temporary storage. The two pairs copy 9 words (36 bytes) from memory address `lr` to `r4`, where the latter is pointing to local variable on the stack (presumably).

Comment: So you have the C++ source of it? Why do you bother with assembly then, find the bug in the source?

Comment: The program crashes at random, and only on Android. The source code doesnt reveal what the actual cause of the bug is.

Comment: well, if the crash happens on the `ldmia`, and it's invalid memory access, then it's due to illegal stack pointer (`lr` actually, not `sp`, which is confusing me a bit, but I'm not an ARM asm expert, coded in asm for it years ago and forgot all). So I would guess the stack memory exhausted then. But without any details, what kind of crash you receive (all the time just one/two address, or random? And crash reason? And values in regs?), nobody will tell you anything meaningful about that assembly, that code looks perfectly normal and has no ordinary simple bug in it. Must be conditions around..

Comment: But having bigger chunk of original source around it, and some architecture design explained would maybe help to get ideas, what is happening. Are you using MT and share some memory between threads? Maybe one thread access memory just after it being released. And with Android and JNI you may be easily breaking some JNI rules, like exceeding references used, etc... (in my personal opinion the author of JNI intentionally made it in a way to keep from C/C++ all the worst parts, and remove everything good about it, and make that an "interface" to java, so everybody gives up and writes Java only).

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm hopelessly confused. But perseverance is the key. I received a SIGBUS error message.All of the rendering is done from one thread, as Android wouldn't allow me to do otherwise.  The actual message I received also read :  Thread 16 "SDLThread" received signal SIGBUS, Bus error. [Switching to Thread 7664.7687]  0xa3b56ec6 in Game::Draw(this=0x2b, renderer=...).

Comment: Wait a second, does `Game::Draw(this=0x2b, renderer=...)` means the `this` pointer was `0x2b`? That doesn't look like valid memory address, so if that class code is manipulating memory there as an `Game` instance, or what is `this`, then it will probably crash quite soon. Well, technically the OS may give the process virtual memory even with such low address, but I don't think linux does that, and also I don't think it would be unaligned to word at least on ARM.

Comment: Could this  be an alignment problem? And if so, do you know any C/C++ code to use to solve it?

Comment: If `this` is `0x2b`, than it's not alignment problem (that's just the reason of crash). It's problem that you have invalid pointer somewhere. 43 is so low, that it may be result of `nullptr` with some offset added. You solve it with C/C++ code by not accessing invalid pointers (i.e. managing your memory correctly, not overwriting anything, etc...). Actually the first thing I would look for is the out-of-memory, maybe some allocation fails due to low memory and returns `nullptr`, which is not checked, and used. BUT looks like the `Game` instance is 0x2b, which is probably not allocated often?